# Jquery not finding nested elements on page

Tags: jquery

Hey guys I have ran into an odd situation. The company I work for uses some SSOs for their pages and on one page in parturlar the sso scripts are super heavy and it is causing my jquery trouble in finding the id of the element it is tied to. Is there a better way to try and do what I am doing?

So below you can see where i am trying to refer to the date text box in the form and it keeps saying that it cannot find it. If I do just #EndDate it does not work. I know it has to do with how nested it is.

Just picture like 50 script tags above my jquery. This is how heavy this file is.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

           var sixMonthLimit = new Date();
           sixMonthLimit.setMonth(sixMonthLimit.getMonth() - 6);

           $("#frmDetails input[id='EndDate']").datepicker(
           {
               minDate: sixMonthLimit,
               maxDate: new Date(),
               changeMonth: true,
               numberOfMonths: 1,
           });


       });

    </script>

       <form id="frmDetails" method="post" runat="server">
           <asp:TextBox ID="EndDate" runat="server" type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
```

Rendered html

```
<input name="EndDate" value="6/12/2019" id="EndDate" type="text" autocomplete="off">
```

Error in debug
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'datepicker' of null
    at HTMLDocument. (DriverWeek.aspx?id=325:17)
    at fire (jquery-1.12.4.js:3232)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.4.js:3362)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.12.4.js:3582)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-1.12.4.js:3617)

Comment: The number of scripts is irrelevant.  Are any of them re-loading jquery, perhaps with a different version?  Are you sure the asp is rendering with `id=EndDate` (look in the rendered source directly) - microsoft have a tendency to "mess" about with things like IDs and they can inherit the parent ID.  Open console after the page has loaded and tells us what you get with `console.log($("#EndDate").length)`

Comment: @j08691 The error i get in the console is that date picker is null. But when i f`12 and inspect the element this is the render i get.

Comment: Can you provide the exact error output?

Comment: @freedomn-m added.

Comment: @msg im already doing that.

Comment: @msg instead of document would "#frmDetails" work in the ready?

Comment: The error is saying that the thing you're calling `.datepicker()` on is null.  If you open the console and do:  `$("#doesnotexist").datepicker()`, you do not get "cannot read property of null" (you just get nothing).  Which doesn't mean it can't find your element, it means the `$("...")` not jquery.  Try:  `jQuery("#frmDetails input[id='EndDate']").datepicker(...`

Comment: `$(document).ready(function () {` is (a) correct way to provide a startup script.

Comment: @freedomn-m THAT WORKED. I guess our sso does something weird to the $

Answer (score -1):

Try single quotes around the attribute selector ID: `$("#frmDetails input[id='EndDate']")`

Comment: Didn't downvote, but while *I* know this makes no difference, sometimes an example is worth confirming it: https://jsfiddle.net/wvdckpg9/

Comment: Thanks @freedomn-m! That's good to know. I was basing that on the jQuery docs https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: You'd need the quotes if you're looking for something with spaces, eg `[data-val='my val']` (and maybe some other cases)